Simple true $\Pi^0_1$ statements unprovable in weak arithmetics
There is an explicitly known 745-state Turing machine where, assuming $\mathrm{ZFC}$ is consistent, the machine never halts, but $\mathrm{ZFC}$ cannot prove this fact. (This is shown in Riebel's thesis The Undecidability of $\mathrm{BB}(748)$. I am wondering if there is a much smaller machine whose halting is unprovable in some much weaker system, like $\mathrm{EFA}$ (exponential function arithmetic) or $\mathrm{PRA}$ (primitive recursive arithmetic). For this purpose, I would like to know if there is a simple $\Pi^0_1$ statement which is known to be unprovable in a weak theory of arithmetic such as those two? In particular, being only about natural numbers would add to the simplicity, and I am aiming for something even simpler than the Paris-Harrington theorem, that would be easily implementable on a Turing machine.

I know there are many known $\Pi^0_2$ statements which are not provable in Peano arithmetic, such as the Paris-Harrington theorem and Goodstein's theorem, and that Harvey Friedman has some examples of $\Sigma^0_1$ statements based on trees whose proofs in some formal theories are extremely long (such as this proposition and $\mathrm{ACA}_0+\Pi^1_2\mathrm{-BI}$).
Riebel has mentioned these kinds of results as well, but for $\mathrm{PA}$ instead of weaker arithmetics, and ran into the same complexity problem:

An interesting task would be to find an upper bound for $\mathrm{PA}$ [for the number of Turing machine states needed to get unprovability] ... There are some other examples of undecidable $\Pi^0_1$ or $\Sigma^0_1$ sentences for $\mathrm{ZFC}$ and $\mathrm{PA}$. For example, we mentioned Harvey Friedman's graph-theoretic theorem in Section 3.4. In addition, Saharon Shelah provided a true $\Pi^0_1$ sentence ... that is not provable in $\mathrm{PA}$. However, implementing these statements ... would require considerable effort due to the complexity of both propositions.


In general, consistency of a recursively axiomatizable theory is a $\Pi^0_1$ statement. You can easily show that any $\Pi^0_1$ statement corresponds to a Turing machine not halting.

@GiorgioGenovesi This is true, but an attempt to implement a consistency statement into a Turing machine using current techniques (e.g. the ones used in Riebel) would likely give a machine with around the same number of states as the 745-state ZFC machine. My goal is a statement in the vein of the Paris-Harrington principle, which is unprovable without at first appearing explicitly logical, that is hopefully simple enough to be implemented in, say, 100 states or fewer.

This might not be exactly what you are looking for but certain restrictions of the Paris Harrington theorem are not provable by systems with insufficient induction. For example $PH_n$, that is Paris Harrington for $n$-tuples can be proven in $\textbf{I}\Sigma_{n+1}$ but not in $\textbf{I}\Sigma_n$. It is also equivalent to a consistency statement over $\textbf{I}\Sigma^0_1$ however it is the consistency of a non recursively axiomatizable theory.

@GiorgioGenovesi This is a nice result! However for application to this question, is there a universal quantifier involved in lower-bounding the size of the homogeneous set? (The set is relatively large but also has at least $m$ elements for some natural number $m$, and the PH principle states "for all $m$, ...")

Yes, you need still to keep the universal quantifiers for the size of the homogeneous set so in particular it is still a $\Pi^0_2$ statement.
